# How many graphs with given average degree and average number of outgoing nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Hi, 
does anyone know if it is known what is the number of undirected graphs with the following properties:

- Number of nodes: $N$, a big number,
- Average degree: $z_1$,
- Average number of outgoing edges $z_2$, where an outgoing edges are all edges leaving one of your neighbors (except the one that connects you to that neighbor).

?

I interested in asymptotic results for large N.

Similarly, the entropy of an ensemble of graphs such that the average degree is $z_1$ and the average number of outgoing edges is $z_2$ is also of interest.

EDIT:
The definition of $z_2$ is here: http://www.santafe.edu/media/workingpapers/00-07-042.pdf on section F, "Numbers of neighbors and average path length". Sorry for the loose definition. $z_2$ is also the number of second neighbors.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the nodes labelled, or not?  (That is, are we counting up to isomorphism, or not?)

Comment: Yes, the nodes are labelled. Sorry, I should have said this before. 

Comment: Also, suppose v,w,and u are vertices of a triangle in the graph.  How are the triangle edges weighted in the definition of z_2?  I can see the edges counted once each or twice each.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.05

Comment: If (v, w, u) is a triangle, the edge (w,u) is to be counted once in the set of "outgoing edges" of the node v. 

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what your outgoing edges are but the number of undirected graphs with 
$N$ labeled vertices and average degree $d$ (which you call $z_1$ but $d$ seems more natural
to me)
is approximatively given by 
$${2^{N(N-1)/2}\choose dN/2}$$
since this is the number of all possible adjacency matrices.

The asymptotics for fixed $d$ and $N\rightarrow\infty$ are then given by 
$$2^{dN^2(N-1)/4}\frac{1}{(dN/2)!}$$
which can be made more explicit using Stirling's formula.